# Генерация карты Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, procedural-generation

Как рандомно генерировать карту-лабиринт-подземелье в Unity похожую на ту, что ниже?

[image]

Пробовал несколько способов генерации.

В [этом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAf9axsyijY) видео интересная генерация, но проблема заключается не в том, что там разные комнаты с разным количеством выходов, а у меня 1 тип - просто клетка, а в том, что там комнаты генерируются до тех пор пока рандомно не появится комната с одним выходом, которая остановит генерацию в этом направлении. То есть при "удачных" обстоятельствах может сгенерироваться карта с миллиардом комнат. Мне это не совсем подходит, в моем случае просто написать количество сгенерированных комнат и все.

Переписал код под свой тип клеток, а не комнат. Все, в целом, работает, но при запуске в основном генерируются карты типа таких:

[image]

То есть они больше похоже на платформы, а не на змеевидный лабиринт. Пока не знаю, как это исправить (в самом низу будет мой код именно с этим вариантом).

В [еще одном варианте](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/24/maze-generation-hunt-and-kill-algorithm) генерации карты преставлен алгоритм, создающий лабиринт. Но мне он вряд ли подходит, так как в нем клетки с тонкими стенками, а у меня вообще нет стен.

В [статье на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/436198/) алгоритм похож на первый, тоже с дверьми, вроде как тоже не подходит.

Пока писал вопрос, все думал про шум Перлина и как можно с ним что-то придумать. Появился вариант каким-то образом (пока не знаю каким) генерировать картинку с шумом и переводить ее в карту - картинка состоит из пикселей с оттенками от черого до белого, оттенки можно перевести в цифры (черный=255, ..., белый=0) и если число больше 100 - ставим на координаты пикселя комнату, если нет - то не ставим. Звучит конечно жутковато.

Вот мой код:

```
private IEnumerator  SpawnPatterns()
    {
        var firstPattern = Pattern.Spawn(gameObject, pattern,
            new Vector3Int(0, 0, 0));
        Patterns.Add(firstPattern);
        var parentPattern = firstPattern;
        for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            var randomSpawnPoint = GetRandomSpawnPoint(parentPattern);
            var p = Pattern.Spawn(gameObject, pattern,
                randomSpawnPoint.transform.position);
            Patterns.Add(p);
            parentPattern = p;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }

    private static SpawnPoint GetRandomSpawnPoint(Pattern parentPattern)
    {
        var spawnPoints = parentPattern.GetComponent<Pattern>().spawnPoints;
        var random = new Random();
        SpawnPoint result;
        while (true)
        {
            var randomNumber = random.Next(0, spawnPoints.Length);
            if (!spawnPoints[randomNumber].used)
            {
                result = spawnPoints[randomNumber];
                parentPattern.GetComponent<Pattern>().spawnPoints[randomNumber].used = true;
                break;
            }
            spawnPoints = spawnPoints
                .Where(val => val != spawnPoints[randomNumber])
                .ToArray();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

У меня так же, как и в видео у клетки есть места вокруг, куба можно поставить следующую клетку. `GetRandomSpawnPoint` возвращает случайное место вокруг для следующей клетки. `SpawnPatterns` сначала ставит начальную клетку, а потом 40 раз с помощью `Pattern.Spawn` создает на сцене клетки. Но как я уже написал, все это больше похоже на платформу, чем на карту в виде змеи и как это исправить, я не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно сгенерировать карту в виде двумерного массива bool и к unity это не имеет никакого отношения.

Алгоритмы это принципы действий которые могут быть описаны на любом языке и c# тут тоже не причем.

---

Вам нужно накинуть некоторое количество клеток которые будут узлами. Можно абсолютно рандома, но есть несколько подходов +/- равноудаленной генерации точек.

[image: Step1]

---

Точки нужно триангулировать (алгоритмом делоне например) что бы построить граф связей.

[image: Step2]

---

Нужно выбрать набор связей из них, что бы все точки были задействованны и из них получилась замкнутая система (из любого узла можно попасть в любой другой). В этом поможет теория графов.

[image: Step3]

---

Остается только отложить выбранные связи в массиве набором разных способов. Под прямым углом из двух линий, прямой зигзаг из трех, на искасок, 45градусов и прямая и т.д.

[image: Step4]

---